# Different Behaviour: graythresh vs multithresh

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wanted to create a binary map of an MRI scan, to divide region of interest from background. I thought of using Otsu's method and I first used 'graythresh' function, but the result was very poor. I tried multithresh function with just the image as input(2 level by default) and obtained a much better result. 
I searched online and the answer I found said they both implement Otsu method and should return the same result. So I was wondering what's the difference, if there is one, or simply why I'm getting different results. Is there a different implementation algorithm that leads to better results in certain cases?

I can't attach the image I'm working on since it's from a private database, but the code I used is this(IM is the image, is loaded from a .nii file and is a matrix of double and I also got the metric output because I needed it in a different task ):

```
[level, metric]=graythresh(IM);
bin_mask=imbinarize(IM,level);
figure
imshowpair(IM,bin_mask,'montage')


[level1, metric1]=multithresh(IM);
bin_mask1=imbinarize(IM,level1);
figure
imshowpair(IM,bin_mask1,'montage')
```

The graythresh result:

[image: graythresh_result]

The multithresh result:

[image: mutithresh_result]

Comment: The only difference I see is that the multithresh returns a threshold in the same range as your original images whereas graythresh returns an element between 0 and 1, see the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/multithresh.html#output_argument_d0e115282) for more information. What is the result of `imbinarize(IM)`?
`

Comment: The result is the one displayed, but you solved my problem, because I haven't considered there was a different range for the threshold value. I'm probabily going to normalize the input image and use graythresh. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in my comment, the output of both functions, i.e. the threshold value, has a different range:

- `multithresh`: same range as the original image
- `graythresh`: normalised range, i.e. between 0 and 1

This is also pointed out in the documentation of [`multithresh`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/multithresh.html#output_argument_d0e115282):

> These thresholds are in the same range as the input image A, unlike
>   the `graythresh` function, which returns a normalized threshold in the
>   range [0, 1].